# What is the maximum limit of Temp directory in Azure Functions on a Consumption plan?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am working in Azure functions and am on a consumption plan, I have some files that I need in the %temp% directory. What is the maximum size of folder allowed for it?

My files would be about 2GB if it means anything. I need them there because I have to perform some operation on them.

Comment: That doesn't feel right... The function instances are supposed to be stateless and transient, i.e. no assumption that your files will be stored between function invocations.

Comment: I understand your point, but my files would be there for not more than 2-3 minutes. I just want them there, perform an operation and then will remove them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a 500MB limit on %temp% files in the Consumption plan. See [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system#temporary-files) for more info.

And of course, avoid making assumptions on those files being there from one call to another. But they can be used for temporary storage within the execution of a request. Or potentially as a cache between requests, as long as you have a fall back if they're not there.